# Writing to Descriptors BLE on iOS device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have created a simple application and my requirement is to write to a descriptor to a Peripheral in order to get Sensor data. There is a method `writeValue(data:Data, descriptor: CBDescriptor)` on the apple documentation, but when I try to execute it I get an `NSException` stating

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Client Characteristic Configuration descriptors must be configured using setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:'".

Can someone please tell me how to write for a descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `WriteValue`, you should call `SetNofifyValue`.

I'm using Xamarin, and the code is as follows (it should be the same principle for xcode)

```
void SwitchNotify(CBCharacteristic mychar,bool SwitchOn)
{
    mychar.Service.Peripheral.SetNotifyValue(SwitchOn,mychar);
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a way of writing the descriptors directly, or why Apple have decided to only allow notify/indicate by using this method. Android and Windows (UWP) both allow direct writing of descriptors.

Comment: and how does one distinguish between Notify or Indicate?